# Dynamic size of form in Play framework 2.7 (Java)

Tags: java, playframework, twirl

I want to create a form application using the **Play framework 2.7** in Java and I would like to create all the fields of my form a certain amount of times, which I don't know before creating it.

Here is one of my model :

```
public class Information {

    public String clientType;
    public String companyName;
    public String name;
    public String firstName;
    public String addressNumber;
    public String apartmentType;

    public Information(String companyName, String name, String firstName, String addressNumber, String clientType,
            String apartmentType) {
        this.clientType = clientType;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.name = name;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.addressNumber = addressNumber;
        this.apartmentType = apartmentType;
    }
}
```

Here, one of my data for the form :

```
public class InformationData {

    @Constraints.Required
    private String clientType;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String companyName;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String name;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String firstName;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String addressNumber;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String apartmentType;

    public InformationData() {
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

And here, a part of my view :

```
@(informationForm: play.data.Form[data.InformationData])
<h1>Informations</h1>

@helper.form(routes.InformationController.validationInformations) {
        @helper.CSRF.formField
        @helper.inputText(
                informationForm("fieldName"),
                Symbol("_help") -> "",
                Symbol("_error") -> informationForm("fieldName").
                   error.map(_.withMessage("ERROR"))
        )
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

In my Controller I have this attribute 
`private final Form<InformationData> form;` which will be used as a parameter of my view (**Twirl** template).

I tried to transform this attribute as a `java.util.List` and in my view use a `@for` loop on this List (which became a Scala Seq in my view) but the validation of the form was not correct : it considered every (for example) `name` field as the same field, so during validation it would just fill the value of every `name` field with the value of the first one (even if the first one is empty and the other aren't).

**EDIT**

I tried to modify the name of all my fields with the current index of the loop (i.e. : `name0` then `name1` and so on), it stopped messing with my fields since they don't have the same name, but my `InformationData` couldn't validate since it can't recognise the names of my fields.

Is it possible to make it understand that `name0` and `name1` should be considered as (different) `name`, by using a HashMap or something ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a list of information, just build the form with a list of information as follow:

```
public class InformationData {

    @Constraints.Required
    private List<Information> informations;

    // setter and getter
}
```

In your webpage you can use the list like this:

```
@(informationForm: play.data.Form[InformationData])

//your html

@for(information<-informationForm.get().getInformations()){
    <p>@information.getName</p>
    <p>@information.getCompanyName</p>
    //all your stuff to print
}

//your html
```

Remember that to retrieve the fields you should "get()" the form before you can access to the methods inside it.

```
informationForm.get().getInformations()
```

To check the length of the list just call the "length" method.

```
informationForm.get().getInformations.length
```

---

For the form part, to build in html you must provide a valid name to build a list of values like

```
@helper.form(routes.InformationController.validationInformations) {
        @helper.CSRF.formField

        <input type="text" name="name[0]" value="">
        <input type="text" name="companyName[0]" value="">
        .....
        <input type="text" name="name[N]" value="">
        <input type="text" name="companyName[N]" value="">

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

If you can't print it with scala beforehand, you should dynamically create your input fields with some javascript.

Comment: What is `forms` that you give in parameters of the view ?

Comment: It was just a typo, it was the package name, if your forms are in the package "forms" you should declare them in scala with `play.data.Form[packageName.InformationData]`

Comment: I have this error : `value getInformations is not a member of play.data.Form[data.InformationData]`

Comment: I edited my question to show you a part of my view. in the `@helper` the `"fieldName"` values should be equal to the name of Information's attributes (name, firstName, etc.) thanks to another parameter, not revelant for now I think. But since my List is empty, I have an error `No value present`

Comment: If you don't know the number of the input fields, before the scala part, you must use some javascript to build your form dynamically

Comment: edited my answwer again to show you how to handle list of input fields @AymericB

Comment: I think this is not what I need, I'm sorry, is it possible to have all of my attributes of `Information` as List or Array (all the same size) instead ? When I create my form I can just use a `@for` loop so it will create name0, firstName0, etc. then name1, firstName1, etc. And store the values in my `public String[] names`, `public String[] firstNames[]` of `InformationData`